# ReactiveUI and Xaml bindings to Observables - When does it work?

Tags: reactiveui

Let's have:

Binding A

```
<Buton IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonCommand.CanExecute}"/>
```

Binding B

```
<ProgressRing IsActive="{Binding ButtonCommand.IsExecuting}"/>
```

I noticed that Binding A worked whereas Binding B didn't.
I wonder why?

ps: I'm not asking how to bind using `ObservableAsPropertyHelper`

UPDATE

Both A and B are consistent in not working (and we should use OPAH).
Indeed I am wrong when I say that Method A works.
Thank you [@Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3516731/adri%C3%A1n-romero) for insisting on that point.

Indeed, in case A, my button command is also bound:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonCommand.CanExecute}"/>
```

I didn't know but the `CanExecute` of my `ReactiveCommand` directly impacts my `Button.IsEnabled` property. Thus I wrongly concluded that the behavior I was observing was due to my binding of `IsEnabled`.

Comment: Because *ButtonCommand.CanExecute* is of type *IObservable<bool>*  and *IsEnabled*property is of type bool, as you said you can use ObservableAsPropertyHelper

Comment: Binding A works. Binding B doesn't. However, the same types are involved.

Comment: You´re right, both are of type *IObservable<bool>*. What about subscribing IsExecuting ?

Comment: FYI, when I turn IsExecuting to an OPAH it works. So I'm really trying to understand why A et B behave differently.

Comment: How do you bind you command with your button? Can you show me the code ?

Comment: I bind exactly as in the xaml in the question really.

Comment: You know, I'm pretty sure that binding A and biniding B doesn´t works, the first work because command binding explcitly disables yor button *IsEnabled*, try to hardcode IsEnabled = false, and do the first binding the button will be disabled, I have difficulties explaining the code, but you can read this: 
https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/50403240c792d6d870fbe74961d5df297b4a1f2e/src/ReactiveUI/CommandBinding.cs

Comment: Your are welcome, may be I should post it as an answer ?

Comment: Sure, you should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding A and binding B doesn't work.

Binding A seems to work because when you bind a ReactiveCommand with a control, when the command is executing IsEnabled property of control gets affected by Command's execution.

For anyone who want's to know the internal [here](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/50403240c792d6d870fbe74961d5df297b4a1f2e/src/ReactiveUI/CommandBinding.cs) is the code

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in the code behind:

```
this.WhenActivated(d=> 
{
  d(this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.ButtonCommand, v => v.ButtonA));
 d(this.WhenAnyObservable(v => v.ViewModel.ButtonCommand.IsExecuting).BindTo(this, v => v.ProgressRing.IsActive));
}
```